# Scan my network externally

Tags: audit, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, scan

So I'm about to undertake Cyber Essentials as our first step towards nailing as best as we can our security. I have done quite a lot of work on locking down our network, however, I would like audit the internal network externally to see if anything is exposed or public accessible (Printers, Routers etc). I use OpenVAS within the network to run scans but is there anything I can use (OpenVas or otherwise) to check the network externally?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for tools? (off-topic, by the way) Does this answer your question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101938/external-vulnerability-scan-of-dmz?rq=1

Comment: Whatever you do, you'll need to talk to your ISP(s) to get their approval and do not block your scans.

Comment: why don't you just host an OpenVAS instance on a server outside your internal network and scan your public IPs with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at cloud based vulnerability scanners. You can also find a number of web based nmap scanners that will scan your public facing IPs for some common ports. ([usually for free](https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/))

If you are UK based (and since you are going for cyber essentials I assume you are) I would also recommend joining the [NCSC Cyber Security Information Sharing Partnership (CiSP)](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/cisp). One of the services they offer is “access to free network monitoring reports tailored to your organisations”. Basically these are reports that will highlight any services on you pubic addresses that look risky.  This is a free service offered to all member organisations.

This will likely allow you pass this section of the Cyber Essential + audit.

Comment: I just noticed I cannot register as I need a sponsor, what do I need to do in this case? @TheJulyPlot

Comment: Yes you would need to get sponsorship from a member organisation, unfortunately I cannot do it due to the semi-anonymous nature of info-sec.se. If you email the NCSC they will be able to help you with a path to sponsorship.

Comment: You may find that the organisation you get in for auditing cyber essentials + may be a member, they could sponsor you.

Answer (score 2):

Either access the internal network through an external VPN, such as another office or home setup VPN. Or test it externally from another office or home.

Once you have the ability to do the above using zenmap (https://nmap.org/zenmap/) will allow you to conduct a port scan of your public facing network address.

A note of caution though: Make sure you do not violate any VPN TOS ; some do not allow you to use their services for port scanning.